# Low Rhino performance on android real device

Tags: android, performance, rhino

I'm having low Rhino performance issues while executing Rhino code on Android real device.

The Rhino context is initiated with a string which represents big JSON object, the total string size is around 120K, to test code performance we wrote a few instrumental tests to check the code performance, however, we are getting not clear result the same code, with the same parameters shows absolutely different results between tests and sample app.

The test performance 10 times faster than the same code is executed as an instrumental test then on it's running as part of the sample app on the same device (G5). BTW the android emulator also shows good performance result.

the code is pretty simple

```
private void init(String jFfunctionsDeclaration) throws ScriptInitException {
        StringBuilder ruleEngineContextBuffer = new StringBuilder();


        //create a JSON object in the string representation, later Rhino context will be initialized with this string  
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> e : scriptObjects.entrySet()) {
            String key = e.getKey();
            String value = e.getValue();
            ruleEngineContextBuffer.append("\nvar ");
            ruleEngineContextBuffer.append(key);
            ruleEngineContextBuffer.append(" = "); // append(" = JSON.parse(");
            ruleEngineContextBuffer.append(value);
        }

        // create and enter safe execution context to prevent endless loop or deadlock in JS
        // because Rhino input it provided from outside
        SafeContextFactory safeContextFactory = new SafeContextFactory();
        rhino = safeContextFactory.makeContext().enter();

        try {
            // the fisrt init step, init Rhino cotext with JS utils methods
            // functions input is the list of JS functions
            sharedScope = rhino.initStandardObjects();
            rhino.evaluateString(sharedScope, functions, "<init1>", 1, null);
            String str = ruleEngineContextBuffer.toString();

            long startContextInit = System.currentTimeMillis();
            rhino.evaluateString(sharedScope, str, "<init2>", 1, null);
            long totalContextInit = System.currentTimeMillis() - startContextInit;
            Log.d(TAG, "Rhino context init duration = " + totalContextInit);
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            throw new ScriptInitException("Javascript shared scope initialization error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

could someone explain me this mystery, thanks.

Comment: Is this being run on the UI thread?

Comment: in the sample Android app it's running on the main thread, will try to run it on the background thread, it's worth testing, good point

Comment: there is no difference while the code is executed on in the UI thread or background thread the result of ten sequential executions
on a real  device is around 460 ms constantly, one more interesting fact, on Emulator I'm getting an excellent result, the performance is getting better it starts from 200ms the first time and then is going down to 10ms after each time. Seem like a real device somehow limits Rhino with CPU

Comment: Switching the thread won't optimize the code itself, rather you'd be able to have a non-blocking process. The emulator isn't a good measurement for these things as it uses your system resources for computation, which is a lot faster than a regular phone. Using a javascript interpreter is an expensive operation, is there some way you can preprocess this?

Comment: I need to learn more about Rhino and its preprocessing options but what confused me it the instrumental test which is executed on the same the real device, same code, however, shows fantastic results 10 times faster, how it could be explained.